# Dynamic width of CSS background images

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have setup menu bar on my page using list and CSS to display the menu elements. To the right of the the menu button, in this case "Home", i have an empty bar element that i would like to extend to the width of the page before i close the menu bar width the end element. I have tried to set the width to 100% which causes it to break to the next line and fill the entire width of the page as displayed below. Any thoughts on how i keep everything on the same line and have the empty element be dynamic in width?

The HTML:

```
<div>
   <li class="menu-home">
      <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-bar"> </li>
   <li class="menu-bar-right"> </li>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
li.menu-bar {
   position: static;
   float: left;
   list-style-type: none;
   background-image: url('top.png');
   border-style: none;
   border-width: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   height: 34px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

The problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `float` the `'home' and 'right'` LIs to the `left and right`, respectively. Any `LIs` that appear below the `home and right` `LIs` in the markup will spill into the center area.

http://jsfiddle.net/gwmFk/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I have implemented your design and everything is now displayed on one line but the center element that i have is continued behind the left and right elements so the rounded corners are disappearing. Any way to have the center element fill out the space between and not the full width of the page?

Comment: I had not implemented the "overflow: hidden;" correctly. Once i added this to the centre element the solution worked - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of your home button you could use `display: inline-block;` on the rest of the bar and give it a right-margin equal to that width (plus any padding or space, etc.)

Do you know the width of the button?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have the width of the button but in some cases more buttons will be added. If I am displaying more than 50 images the images are split into pages and a next and back button is added so I was really looking for the width to be dynamic so it would just fill out the space

Comment: If that's the case, I recommend that you look at Twitter Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html). It is exactly what you're looking for. Look at the scaffolding page and focus on fluid layouts. You should also take a peek at the other features to see if any of them are things that you're going to be trying to implement - Bootstrap has a great set of jQuery plugins that you can add on.